# in Vsual Studio C++ OffsetRgn not working>

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
void CBallBounceView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CBallBounceDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;
    CString str; 
    str.Format(_T("Counter = %d"), counter);
    CRgn   rgnA,copyeed;
    VERIFY(rgnA.CreateEllipticRgn(50, 50, 150, 150));
    CBrush brA;
    VERIFY(brA.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0)));
    VERIFY(pDC->FillRgn(&rgnA, &brA));      // rgnA Red Filled
    int nOffsetResult = rgnA.OffsetRgn(500, 100);
    ASSERT(nOffsetResult != ERROR && nOffsetResult != NULLREGION);
    
}
```

I am trying to offset the ellipse region but it is not offsetting. I am new in visual studio C++;
I am using Visual studio 2019.

Comment: Not sure what exactly your problem is. Are you expecting the drawn area to be moved when you offset the region? Doesn't work like that ... maybe draw again with a different colour after your `OffsetRgn` call and you'll see that it *has* moved.

Comment: @Adrian Mole, Thanks it is moved!!. So in this way we can move only the region.But how can we move the entire thing, i am trying to create a bouncing ball animation, any idea.

Comment: Bad assert.  An elliptic region is always a COMPLEXREGION, unless it is very small.  Takes a bunch of rectangular regions to approximate the ellipse.  You should only assert for ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, once output has been rendered to the given device context (as by your `pDC->FillRgn(&rgnA, &brA)` call), any *subsequent* changes to that region will *not* change the displayed output.

In order to do this, you will need to perform a cycle of operations:

1. Draw the object in its original position.
2. Then, when moved, erase that *original* object; and...
3. Draw the object in its new position.
4. Repeat each time you move the object.

You typically perform the 'erase' operation by drawing the object each time using the `XOR` (exclusive or) 'mix mode' on the target device context. Thus, the *first* time you draw this, it will paint the object over the background, and the *second* time, it will restore that background. You can use the [`CDC::SetROP2(R2_XORPEN)` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?view=msvc-160#setrop2) to set that mode.

Here's a 'scruffy' (but runnable) program demonstrating the use of this `XOR` drawing technique. It uses 'raw' Windows GDI calls (rather than MFC) and is a Console-Mode program, but it will hopefully show the basic principles of the technique:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

#define BLOBSIZE 20
#define MOVESTEP  5

int main()
{
    SetProcessDPIAware(); // Comment this line out if using 'older' versions of Windows.
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    RECT rc; GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    int x = 50, y = 30;
    int dx = MOVESTEP, dy = MOVESTEP;
    SetROP2(hDC, R2_XORPEN);
    SelectObject(hDC, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
    SelectObject(hDC, GetStockObject(NULL_PEN));
    do {
        Ellipse(hDC, x, y, x + BLOBSIZE, y + BLOBSIZE); // First call: Draws the object
        Sleep(10); // Here, we just wait, but you can do whatever else you want between moves
        Ellipse(hDC, x, y, x + BLOBSIZE, y + BLOBSIZE); // Second call: erase it
        x += dx;
        if ((dx > 0 && x >= rc.right - BLOBSIZE) || (dx < 0 && x == 0)) {
            Beep(1000, 10);
            dx *= -1;
        }
        y += dy;
        if ((dy > 0 && y >= rc.bottom - BLOBSIZE) || (dy < 0 && y == 0)) {
            Beep(1000, 10);
            dy *= -1;
        }
    } while (!(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000)); // Press spacebar to quit!
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not the way regions work, they don't "lock" to anything that gets painted.  Check the comment I left for the real reason.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't doubt the accuracy of your remark(s). But I'm not sure I get the point about 'locked' output: Once a region is painted to a DC, the pixels are set; changing the region afterwards won't affect those pixels ... or have I got this completely wrong?

Comment: That's true, but he's complaining about the assert failing.  It should fail with the given ellipse size.